# October CMS Plugin with reassignable variables / dynamic state

Tags: octobercms

I am trying to create an October CMS plugin with variables that can be changed and updated. The application uses an API to a booking service, so the "state" that I am trying to preserve is the items in the shopping cart, meanwhile the customer should continue to search through available items and add them while the plugin "remembers" what is stored in the shopping cart. When an item is added to the cart the plugin has to remember what was already in the cart, not only what is being added. I cannot find any way to store information in the plugin component. I do not want to use a database/models to store the data because it should only be temporarily stored.

I've tried to re-assign variables in my class definition without success, and I've tried to reference the variables in the page with no success.

```
$current_value = $this->page['var']; //returns nothing
```

But I am not able to reference anything with this, I can only set the page variables, not read them.

My Plugin.php file:

```
use Cms\Classes\ComponentBase;
class MyPlugin extends ComponentBase
{
    public $var;
    public $var_new;

    public function componentDetails()
    {...}
    public function defineProperties()
    {...}
    public function init()
    {
      $this->var = "value 1";
      $this->var_new = "value 2";
    }
    public function onAddItem()
    {
      $this->page['var'] = $this->var_new;
      $this->var_new = "value 3";
    }
```

My default.htm file:

```
{% set var = __SELF__.var %}

<form  data-request="{{__SELF__}}::onAddItem" data-request-update="'{{__SELF__}}::update': '#retrieved_events'">
  <input type="submit" value="Update Value">
</form>

<ul id="retrieved_events">
  {% partial __SELF__~'::update'  var=var %}
</ul>
```

My update.htm file:

```
<p>{{var}}</p>
```

When the page loads, the initial value of "var" on the page is "value 1", as I expect it should be. Then I click the submit button and its changed to "value 2", then I want to click it a third time and the value should be "value 3", However its still value 2. Is there any way to accomplish this? Reassigning the object parameters within methods seems to do nothing, its seems like I am only working with a local scope of the function and the initially set values of the object and I have nothing persistent to work with.

Comment: I think I found the solution to my problem. I can set a value using setcookie("var", "cookievalue") and access it using $_COOKIE["var"] to achieve the behaviour that I want

Comment: I think you can use **cache** of octobercms. https://octobercms.com/docs/services/cache

Comment: Thank you, I am using the cache now, I think this should work for me. The problem I ran into with using cookies is i was serializing an array to store as a cookie, but the array was too large and it would not store, I think I was above the allowed limit for the browser.

Comment: Glad to help you. the cache store data in files so you won't have any problem's when data is large